Is there any final theory of Karma
Everybody put a Karma theory in a slightly different way,but the two directions should be separated  first of all:

Samskaras and vasanas create desires habits and inclinations working from inside. At the same time a karmic response is something coming from the world as a systematic reaction to our actions done with attachment to result. [1]

Samskaras and vasanas are the storage Karma itself. Whatever we do is stored in a symbolic form as a samskara which can manifest later in a psyche causing some actions which lead to certain experiences in a material world.[2]


The problem with the first approach is that it lacks a storage of carmic "records".
The problem with the second is at least I don't understand how Samskara of bad action would cause a bad response. It would be logical that Samskara of a good action cause more good actions in the future, same for bad. But why impression of a bad action would cause a bad response from the world is unclear. So here we should deny the idea of Karma as a balancing force, i.e. equal pleasure causes equal pain or equal kind action returns in an equal beneficial circumstance.
In this second theory it is tempting to say that the world is totally projected by the mind so to explain that responses of pain are created along with the experiences of pleasure. But in this case we have no place for objective world, which is there due to the fact that Jivas have some common space for interactions. There should be at lease some part which is objective. And Karmic response should work through this objective part as well, because it comes from the material world in a major part of cases.
So is there a conclusive theory including all this?
[1] "Prarabda is a power that, while remaining invisible, brings happiness and unhappiness. This creates favorable and unfavorable waves in the world and the mind"  p.118
"I said that karma forms prarabdha and karma also releases one from the bondage of prarabdha" p. 120
Sw. Shivom Tirth, "Churning of the heart" vol 2
[2] "Karma is the chain of actions created by man in his life. Or, in
other words, it is the effects of all the activities in life." "Now I will explain karma in a different way. Every action
as momentum and at the end of the momentum a seed drops.
First the seed is in the form of a memory, then the memory
is transformed into a samskara" "Man’s consciousness is like an ocean. It has untold drops
of karma and therefore it is very difficult to put an end to all
this." page 14
Teachings of Sw. Satyananda Saraswati, Vol.2,

Gave references. I'm not sure whether those scriptures count as scriptures here, but this should not cancel the question whether there is a final theory on that.
